# Bracket to lay 3× 2x6 on top a 4x4 post?

Tags: exterior, beam, support, brackets, swing

I am trying to re-purpose existing 4x4 exterior posts to install a swinging seat.

The kit that we are using calls for the top beam to be composed of at least 3x 2x6 pieces.

Does anyone know of an exterior use approved, metal bracket that would be good for my use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the post and beam to have the same width dimension. Although you're trying to recycle, it's best to build this with a **6x6 beam and 6x6 posts**. It will be stronger and look nicer anyways. Attach them together with the **Simpson LCE4** seen below. A total of 4 of them will be needed and each of them will need (14) 0.162 x 3 1/2 into the beam and (10) 0.162 x 3 1/2 into the post.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it should work. I have reached out to the swing kit manufacturer if 4x6 lumber would do. The kit is meant for 4' to 6' wide swing seat, whereas my columns are about 42" apart. So I am hoping that a single 4x6 would work in my case instead of a 3x 2x6s...

Answer (score 1):

Try: Simpson CCQ4.62-3.62SDS

Or for end conditions: ECCQ4.62-3.62SDS

https://www.strongtie.com/sdsscrewcolumncaps_columncaps/ccq-eccq_productgroup_wcc/p/ccq.eccq#LoadTables

Click on load tables for exact dimensions.

Comment: I was thinking this as well, but then you'd need to have the straps rotated 90 degrees so the cap is secured for the torsion forces on the beam. This seems like a special order.

Comment: Thanks. Given the extra cost of these compared to nominal cost of in stock brackets that would work with 4x lumber... I have reached out to the swing kit manufacturer to see if the kit would with m relatively short span (~ 42") and a 4x6 beam.